# how can we set up Proxy server dealing with UDP packets?

Tags: sockets, networking, proxy, udp, packet

Usually we can set up a proxy server by some kind of tools such as CCProxy which provides proxy services for HTTP, SOCKS, FTP packets etc.
Also, Proxifier or Proxycap is used to forward the packets of specific application on the client PC.
However, when UDP packets are forwarded to the proxy server, these packets cannot be correctly forwarded to the destination originally the application wanted them to go.
When I use a network analyzer to observe the UDP traffic flow, the UDP packets are just passed to the proxy server from my PC without going to the correct destination finally.

Besides, someone suggested that the UDP relay is not enabled in the proxy server so the UDP packets cannot be routed successfully. How can I enable the UDP relay function on the proxy server?(Assume that I can control the proxy server completely)

Answer (score 17):

Any kind of proxy, whether it is for TCP or UDP, needs to be told where to forward outgoing packets to. That also allows the proxy to know who is requesting the forwarding so it can route matching inbound packets back to that same requester.

Lets assume SOCKS, for example.  SOCKS v4 does not support UDP (or IPv6), but [SOCKS v5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928) does.  However, it requires the requesting app to establish a TCP connection to the SOCKS proxy and ask it to forward UDP packets on the app's behalf until that TCP connection is closed.

Tools like CCProxy, Proxycap, Proxifier, etc work (for TCP, anyway) by intercepting outgoing TCP conections and redirecting them to the proxy server, transparently handling any proxy handshaking to set up forwarding, before then allowing any application data to flow through the TCP connection.  Once the TCP connection has been established, the proxifier does not need to do anything more with the connection since the app is now talking directly to the proxy.

I do not know if such tools support UDP.  It would be much harder to implement, since there is no outgoing connection to redirect.  Every outbound UDP packet would have to be intercepted, then the proxifier would have to check if it already has its own [SOCKS v5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928) TCP connection associated with the packet's local/remote tuple and if not then create a new one and send the necessary UDP forwarding handshake, then encapsulate every outbound UDP packet for that tuple and send it to the proxy's outbound IP/Port, and receive every matching inbound UDP packet for that tuple from the proxy so it can be de-encapsulated and forwarded to the app's local IP/Port that sent out the original outbound UDP packet.  And because UDP is connection-less, the proxifier would have to also implement a timeout mechanism on its [SOCKS v5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928) TCP connection to the proxy so it can eventually be closed after a period of UDP traffic being idle.

That is a LOT more work for a UDP proxifier to do compared to TCP.

And that is just for SOCKS.  HTTP/FTP proxies do not support UDP at all (since HTTP/FTP are TCP-based protocols).  And there are other tunnel/proxy protocols as well, which may or may not have their on UDP capabilities.

So you have to check the capabilities of your proxifier tool to see if it supports UDP or not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you sort of answered your own question, maybe without knowing it. You see, the actual program called "proxifier" CANNOT pass through UDP (they even say so). However, the program actually called "ProxyCAP" CAN and DOES pass through UDP.

Source: personal experience. I run an app called NetShare and another "proxy" app on my (non rooted) android phone to avoid using it's native "hotspot" tethering (to avoid usage/limits/detection). I then use ProxyCAP to "force" all TCP & UDP traffic from my PC to the phone's respective Proxies. Netshare is the HTTP/TCP proxy, and the other one is a ShadowSOCKS proxy (for UDP). ProxyCAP successfully "forces" ALL out-bound traffic, both TCP and UDP to their two respective "proxies" on my phone. Then, all traffic on my phone just looks like the phone is using it, and so it doesn't count against my "hotspot" tethering limits! UDP was also the most important to me seeing as many games require it AND do not have proxy settings!

So, to further clarify, you would indeed need two proxy's. One to handle TCP and one to handle UDP (one HTTP and one ShadowSOCKS). Though as far as "catching" it and "forcing" all out-bound traffic (both TCP and UDP) from a machine to their respective proxy's; ProxyCAP *will* do that! For UDP you're going to want a ShadowSOCKS proxy!

The "other" proxy (ShadowSOCKS) for my phone, in the event anyone is curious, is "android proxy server".

Comment: List of programs/apps mentioned in my answer:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kha.prog.mikrotik&pli=1
,
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.adonet.proxyevery
,
https://www.proxycap.com/